# Transfer Class-based view to another

Tags: django

I created a DetailView class that can receive links from categories or posts from a website. In the “get_object ()” method, I identify if it is Category or Post models (by url slug). The URLs for this class are listed below:

```
/category/

/category/subcategory/

/category/post/

/category/subcategory/post/
```

The class got too long because the categories and posts have specific behaviors.

I was wondering if it is possible to "transfer" one class to another to handle specific information?

For example:

`GenericView redirect to CategoryView after identifying that it is the url: / category / or for PostView, if it is / category / post /`

NOTE: I am transferring the Wordpress site to Django, so I cannot change the url structure.

Is there any way to do this? Do you suggest another better solution?

Comment: If DetailView does not make things easier, why do you use it?

Comment: What do you recommend @Txema?

Comment: To create your own regular view, seems not to be a use case for DetailView,